# Why is empty string changed into -n expression in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

Taken this snippet:

```
$ [[ ""=="foo" ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ -n ==foo ]]
+ echo yes
yes
```

How does `[[ ""=="foo" ]]` turn into `[[ -n ==foo ]]` ?

The RC was of course missing spaces around `==` - after adding them, it works as expected:

```
$ [[ "" == "foo" ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ '' == \f\o\o ]]
+ echo no
no
```

But still i cannot understand why it behaved like this?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: The `[[ -n var ]]` is the same as or a shorthand to `[[ var ]]`

Comment: You need spaces around `==`.

Comment: @Barmar i know that - RC is mentioned in the question itself. but the actual question is "why"

Comment: @Jetchisel it appears so. did know that... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not changing the empty string into `-n`.

The string `""=="foo"` is equivalent to the string `==foo`. The trace output always shows strings in their simplest format, without unnecessary quotes.

A conditional expression that just contains a single string with no operators is true if the string is not empty. That's what the `-n` operator tests, so the `-x` expansion shows it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Any operand that isn't preceded or followed by an operator is treated to have an equal operation as `-n <operand>`.  Operators also need to be isolated with spaces to be distinguished.  For a list of operators run `help test`.  Also run `help [[` to see how the keyword is different from the `[` and `test` builtins.